# Store the top half and low half of a 32 bit number

Tags: mips, store, bit

Is there a way to store the 16 leftmost bits, and the 16 rightmost bits of a binary number in MIPS?
For example, let's say I have the binary number: `1111 1111 1111 0000 0011 1111 0011 1100`. Now, I want to store `1111 1111 1111 0000` in `$t0` and the other half in `$t1`. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use the shift and AND instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out.